# How is it possible to Adsense CPC even below $0.01?

Tags: google-adsense

I have a blog and almost all my readers are from Sri Lanka. I know Adsense CPC is very low for Sri Lanka. But I thought it should be at least $0.01.

In the last week I have around 8000 page views with 400 clicks. I have earned only $2.9.

Just $2.9 for 400 clicks. It is around $0.007 CPC.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Adsense CPC is proportional to what advertisers are willing to pay per click. Two major factors that determine CPC follow:

1. Niche - Your website topic may not have high-paying advertisers. For example, advertisers from Niches like healthcare, insurance, etc., tend to spend bigger.
2. Location - Adsense displays both contextual and personalized ads. CPCs are usually higher in developed countries like the US where income levels are high.

So, if you focus on AdSense, either you should target the right audience or at least the right niche or preferably both.

**Update**: I am adding more explanation as OP wanted to know if CPC can be as low as 0.007 USD.

0.007 USD translates to 1.40 Srilankan Rupee. 68% of click cost is shared with publishers ( https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/180195?hl=en). So the actual cost spent by an advertiser (on average) is around 2.05 in Srilankan currency. This cost is entirely possible as it is for click and not for a sale or conversion. Assuming an advertiser gets a conversion rate of 1%, he would have spent 100 x 2.05 = 205 per conversion.

Comment: My question is can it possible even below $0.01 CPC?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have updated my answer with more explanation.